# Django BooleanField keeps return False (empty) regardless if checked or not

Tags: django, forms, boolean, models

As stated in the title.  BooleanField wont return True even if checked.  This one is driving me nuts!

First I retrieve checkboxes based on a list of field id's based on a model.

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        fields = Fields.objects.all()
        for field in fields:
            field_name = field.ID
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'checkbox-small'}), label=field_name)
```

The handler never returns True even if checked on in the DOM.

models.py

```
def myFormHandler(request):
    siteDictionary = getDictionary(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, error_class=DivErrorList, auto_id='%s')
        if form.is_valid():
            fields = Fields.objects.all()
            for field in fields:
                if form.cleaned_data[field.ID]:
                    print "Finally returned true!"
    else:
        form = MyForm()
        siteDictionary['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('page.html', siteDictionary, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any ideas?  Thanks for your help.

**EDIT** Here is the template

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="table-all">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="check" class="checkall checkbox-small" /></th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for field in form %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ field }}</td>
            <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="pager" class="pager">
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="green"><span>Submit</span></button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the template look like?

Answer (score 2):

Your fields aren't inside your HTML form element, so aren't submitted.

Comment: Yessir!  This was part of the problem anyways (and I had everything inside of the form before but I took it out for some reason out of frustration I think).  Alasdair's suggestion was also necessary.  My field ID's were integers and converting them to strings fixed my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is `field.ID` an integer? If so, you need to coerce it to a string when generating `field_name`.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        fields = Fields.objects.all()
        for field in fields:
            field_name = str(field.ID)
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'checkbox-small'}), label=field_name)
```

Comment: Yes!  This was apart of my problem as well.  (my form placement was wrong too).  Question:  Why does it matter if it's a string vs integer?  I was still following an integer indexing throughout the request.  Thanks again for your help!  I'd upvote but I don't have 15 pts yet =(

Comment: Try printing request.POST in your view. You'll see that all the keys are strings, so Django cannot match the post data to your fields with integers for names.

Comment: As an aside, I would avoid using names and ids that start with digits (setting `auto_id='%s'` means the field id is a number) This isn't valid in HTML 4 (see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)), although it's ok in HTML5. It might not matter in some browsers, but sooner or later it might cause some odd behaviour that takes an afternoon to track down.